# How to spot a phrase/word in a cell of a dataframe, using R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Having a data.frame like 'df', I would like to spot this exact phrase "keratinization [GO:0031424]" in each cell of the column 'bio_process'. Afterwards, I want to create a new vector with 'ID' of the observations that the match occured.

```
ID <- c("Q9BYP8", "Q17RH7", "Q6L8G8", "Q9BYR4")
bio_process <- c("keratinization [GO:0031424]", "NA", "keratinization [GO:0031424]", "aging [GO:0007568]; hair cycle [GO:0042633]; keratinization [GO:0031424]")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID,bio_process))
```

in order to acheive this, I applied a `for loop`. I used the `%in%` into the loop, like this:

```
n <- 4
ids <- vector(mode = "character", length = n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  if ("keratinization [GO:0031424]" %in% df$bio_process[i]) {
    ids[i] <- data$ID[i]
    }
  }
```

As a result I would like the content of 'ids' vector to be like this one below.

```
"Q9BYP8" "Q6L8G8" "Q9BYR4"
```

However, `%in%` does not work for the cells were 'keratinization [GO:0031424]' is not the only content.

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `grepl` in Base-R

```
df$ID[grepl("keratinization \\[GO:0031424\\]",df$bio_process)]

[1] Q9BYP8 Q6L8G8 Q9BYR4
```

note I had to escape the `[` character with `\\` as square brackets have special meaning in regex.

Comment: You don't need to escape the closing square bracket.